# Learning Yii2: many to many relations eagerly loading

Tags: activerecord, yii2

Looking at this link: [Yii2 Active Record](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html)

At this section:

> When eagerly loading a relation, you can customize the corresponding relational query using an anonymous function. For example,

```
// find customers and bring back together their country and active orders
// SELECT * FROM `customer`
// SELECT * FROM `country` WHERE `id` IN (...)
// SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE `customer_id` IN (...) AND `status` = 1
$customers = Customer::find()->with([
   'country',
   'orders' => function ($query) {
        $query->andWhere(['status' => Order::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
    },
])->all();
```

I have 3 tables:

customers: Fields: customer_id, customer_name

colors: Fields: color_id, color_name

customer_colors: Fields: id, color_customer_id, color_color_id

Customer 1 is connected to the colors: Purple and Orange
Customer 2 is connected to color: Orange

I am trying to get all the customers that have the color Orange with this code:

```
$data = Customers::find()->with([
            'colors' => function($query) {
                $query->andWhere(['color_name' => 'Orange']);
            }
        ])->all();
```

The result I get back has all the customers in it, regardless of what colors they have or don't have.

I also tried to use `color_id` instead of `color_name`, got the same result.

Why is that?

Comment: try `joinWith()` instead of `with()`.

Comment: @InsaneSkull Thank you but I am trying to understand why is their example don't work. Not how to do it in a different way.
They don't use joinWith they use with. What's the point of having andWhere if it's doing nothing?

Comment: yes, `with()` also work , show your generated relation.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

My relations were declared in the customers model.

The minute I declared it in the Colors model, it worked.

Thank you @InsaneSkull for the help.